# How to fix MiKTeX209-popt.dll (impossible to find)

Tags: miktex, texstudio, miktex-update, miktex2.9

I have installed MiKTeX 64 bit.

And, reinstalled TeXstudio 2.12.6.

But, now, I see this error:

[image]

but the file is present, and all the links (in TeXstudio) are right.

There are someone that know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Got the same error too when I installed TeXstudio 2.12.6. I had to reinstall MiKTeX.

Comment: Normally this means that the dll and/or the executable is not up-to-date. Run the update manager (admin), check also with the package manager (admin) if there are uninstalled package beginning with miktex (synchronize first), and run (as admin) `initexmf --admin --mklinks`